# ConTeXt: rounded corners table-cells mismatch rectangulars height

Tags: context

When using rounded corners for some `TABLE` cells with the following setup

```tex
\setupTABLE[row]  [each][background=color,align={middle,lohi},offset=.75ex,frame=off]
\setupTABLE[row]  [first][backgroundcolor=darkred,headcolor=white]
\setupTABLE[first][first][corner=8]
```

the rounded ones slightly mismatch with the rectangular ones:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some (re)tries I found that using `rulethickness=0pt` like so

```tex
\setupTABLE[row]  [each][background=color,align={middle,lohi},offset=.75ex,frame=off]
\setupTABLE[row]  [first][backgroundcolor=darkred,headcolor=white,rulethickness=0pt]
\setupTABLE[first][first][corner=8]
```

somehow get the job done.

[image]